# Stopping div transparency and then recreating it

Tags: css, exception, html, transparency

I am creating a site for my hometown in Wordpress. Because I want that the user sees the whole background image, I modified the main div's transparency property. So far so good. However, I also want to have a Google Maps box on the website. Since it is also part of the main div, the Google Maps box is also transparent (which makes it really hard to see what's going on). I wonder if there is a way to add an exception to the main div's transparency just for the Google Maps box.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

This is the CSS3 code I use. cbox is the main div that needs to be 0.80 transparent. gmapsframe is the box for the Google Maps.

```
.cbox {
        overflow: hidden;
    width: 958px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    background: url("images/cbox.png") center 1px no-repeat;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.gmapsframe {
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

It doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: I don't think it needs code, it is a simple enough question

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this,

Option 1 is to override the parent transparency. Apply this to your maps div

```
<div id='transparentDiv' style='background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);'>

    <div id=mapDiv style='background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);'></div>

</div>
```

Here is a JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/V9Y5f/

Option 2 is to use absolute or relative positioning:

```
<div id='containerDiv'>

    <div id='transparentDiv' style='background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);'>

    </div>    

    <div id='mapDiv' style='position: relative; top: -30px;'></div>

</div>
```

Here is a JS Fiddle example using relative positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/p7TXU/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `opacity` property of CSS, use `rgba` on the parent, as it handles opacity, and does not affect any children.

Ps.: You don't need to change anything regarding transparency on any children of that div.

[More info regarding rgba](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/).

Comment: I tried to change the opacity: 0.8; to rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8). There is no transparency at all now.

Comment: @user3154699 I didn't notice you are using a image as background.. Well.. rgba only works with color backgrounds, for image, you have 2 options: you can reduce the image transparency, or you can put the map in a different div (like the SLC option 2 said so, but using opacity property again).